# Meaning of "details" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am puzzled by the use of the word *details* in [this comic strip](http://www.channelate.com/2016/07/31/worst/) and in particular [its bonus](http://www.channelate.com/extra-panel/20160731/).

Transcript:

> **Man**: Just go introduce yourself. What's the worst that could happen?
>   **Woman**: The worst? Like, what if he's a rapist?!
>   **Man**: A rapist?! Naaaaw.
>   **Woman**: Fine, **you** go introduce yourself to him.
>   **Man**: But... But I don't wanna get serial killed!
>   **Unknown man** (bonus panel): Where the hell are my details?

The definition I found for *detail* are the following ([Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/detail)):

> - An individual fact or item
> - A minor decorative feature of a building or work of art
> - Itemized information about someone

None of these definition seem to fit with the strip. I am guessing it's intended to be a joke about the man being, in fact, a killer, but I don't understand the punchline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in this case it's referred to "details" as in "detailed drawing," which would be your second definition. Compare with this definition (from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/)):

> [**detailed**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/detailed)
>   (Of a work of art) executed with many minor decorative features:
>   "*an exquisitely detailed carving*"

In this particular comic, the artist is making a joke about the figures in the background being drawn like silhouettes instead of with any  features (like hair, faces, or clothes).

It's common for artists to omit features on background characters, as otherwise they'd spend a significant amount of time drawing something that is only tangentially related to the story. In this case, the silhouetted people in the background help convey that the foreground characters are in a club, bar, or pub. Those silhouetted figures being more detailed wouldn't add anything to the comic.

Comment: I'll admit that I didn't see the joke immediately either, @ThomasFrancois.